# как сверстать полосы под заголовком

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сверстать полосы под заголовком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же просто полоски, без хитрой позиции...

Можно было дать псевдоэлементам и `border-bottom`, вместо `background-color`

```css
.moo {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.moo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px; width: 60px;
  background-color: #c9a461;
  bottom: -5px; left: 45px;
}
.moo:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px; width: 50px;
  background-color: #c9a461;
  bottom: -5px; left: 138px;
}
```

```html
<span class="moo">НОМЕРА И ЦЕНЫ</span>
```

Comment: спасибо большое